# How to improve UITableView scrolling when data is calculated on the go in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

Before changes to the way we return cells in the `cellForRow:` method, I remember I would be able to check `if cell == nil`, and basically have two separate areas for cell-related-customization (properties that apply to all cells vs. only to some). However with `dequeueReusableCell:` I am unsure how to handle this and put it off until I was able to get all my cells populated properly -- but seemingly at the expense of a great amount of CPU and Memory usage. Here is my code in `cellForRow:` currently:

```
    if case (1...(days.count + 1), 2...(hours.count + 2)) = (indexPath.column, indexPath.row) {

            let cell = spreadsheetView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: String(describing: ScheduleCell.self), for: indexPath) as! ScheduleCell

            let legs : NSArray = importedDict.object(forKey: "legs") as! NSArray

            print(hours![indexPath.row - 2])

            var profits : Array<Double> = []

            if let singleLegDict2 = legs as? [[String:AnyObject]] {

                print (singleLegDict2)
                for singleLegDict in singleLegDict2 {
                    let dict = singleLegDict as NSDictionary

                    let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
                    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd"
                    let datee = dateFormatter.date(from: days![indexPath.column - 1] as! String)!
                    let datee2 = dateFormatter.date(from: dict.object(forKey: "expiry") as! String)!

                    let calendar = Calendar.current

                    // Replace the hour (time) of both dates with 00:00
                    let date1 = calendar.startOfDay(for: datee)
                    let date2 = calendar.startOfDay(for: datee2)

                    let components = calendar.dateComponents([.day], from: date1, to: date2)
                    let doub = Double(components.day!)

                    let years = doub * 0.00273972602

//                    let under : NSNumber = dict.object(forKey: "underlying") as! NSNumber
                    let strike : NSNumber = dict.object(forKey: "strikePrice") as! NSNumber
                    let interest1 : NSNumber = dict.object(forKey: "interest") as! NSNumber
                    var interest2 = interest1 as! Double
                    interest2 = interest2/100
                    let userIV : NSNumber = NSNumber(value: Double(dict.object(forKey: "userIV") as! String)!)
                    var userIV2 = userIV as! Double
                    userIV2 = userIV2/100

                    var type = 0
                    if dict.object(forKey: "putCall") as! String == "CALL" {
                        type = 0
                    } else {
                        type = 1
                    }

                    let theo = getTheoreticalOptionPrice(forUnderlyingPrice: hours![indexPath.row - 2] as! NSNumber, withStrike: strike, withInterestRate: NSNumber(value: interest2), withVolatility: NSNumber(value: userIV2), withTimeToExpirationInYears: NSNumber(value: years), withType: NSNumber(value: type))
                    let userC : NSNumber = NSNumber(value: Double(dict.object(forKey: "userCost") as! String)!)
                    let quan : NSNumber = dict.object(forKey: "quantity") as! NSNumber
                    let diff = (theo - (userC as! Double)) * (quan as! Double)
                    print(theo, (userC as! Double))
                    profits.append(diff)
                }

            }

            print(profits)

            var sumedArr : Double = profits.reduce(0, {$0 + $1}) as Double
            sumedArr = sumedArr * 100

            if sumedArr < 0 {
                cell.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 0.8667, green: 0.1804, blue: 0.1804, alpha: 1.0)

            } else {
                cell.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 0.3843, green: 0.7686, blue: 0.1608, alpha: 1.0)
            }

            cell.label.text = String(format: "%.0f", sumedArr)

            return cell
        }
```

Any ideas on how to speed that up? Is the only way going to be preloading the data and then only referencing it in `cellForRow:`? How would I go about addressing this situation given the calculations I am doing per cell?

I don’t need the cells to reload their data every time they are scrolled to. If all the cells load their data once when the view loads, and that data was just displayed — that would be perfect.

With that in mind, I tried adding a check to see if the cell’s label was populated or not, and only if not, do all those calculations (assuming this would be the first loading of the table view). While that improved scrolling performance, the cells weren’t properly displaying and were completely out of order. Help?

**Update:** I have moved the heavy calculations to a background thread and now experience smooth scrolling. However, the cells still flicker because they are still regenerating their data each time they are shown. What is the easiest way to cache the cells so that they load once when the `tableView` is shown, and then scroll smoothly because they reference already loaded data?

Comment: Do you know what slows down your app? Have you run your app (on a real device) with profiling (Instruments / Time profiler)?

Comment: From what I can tell, it’s my call to getTheoreticalOptionPrice which is a function that uses JavaScriptCore to do some pretty hearty calculations (that really only need to be done once).

Comment: if that `JavaScriptCore` code can be moved out of your `cellForRow` function, pre-computed and then referenced in 0(1) time at cell-creation time, you'd be much better off. Also, look at dispatching that heavy-computation to a background thread.

Comment: Let me try your idea with the background thread... Update: Using a background thread works and the scrolling is smooth, however, obviously it still does not seem to know that I need to load all the cells a single time, display their data, and then scrolling should reuse those loaded cells. Currently, with the background thread, the cells flicker as they regenerate their data, which even if does not slow down the table view's scrolling, I can't imagine is a good practice. Any ideas?

Comment: Why do you use `JavaScriptCore` in the first place, if I might ask?

Comment: A function I need to use is written in JS. I suppose I could rewrite it in Swift, but is the actual reading/compiling of JavaScript the CPU/memory hog or is only what that code is doing? In other words, generally would it be significantly worth it?

Comment: Sulthan, your answer was best. I rewrote the code in Swift and the performance was greatly improved. I'd like to accept your answer, if I may?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using JavaScriptCore to calculate data for each cell in cellForRow was slowing down my tableView beyond fixing. The only alternative was to cache the data in an Array beforehand and then display it. However, for my use-case, this was not an option.

I rewrote the JavaScript in Swift and the scrolling improved.

Answer (score 1):

I do not understand why it is so important for the performance of your app to know whether a tableView cell has been initialized newly or is re-used. But if so, you can handle it as earlier. The [docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitableview/1614891-dequeuereusablecell) say:

> If you registered a class for the specified identifier and a new cell
>   must be created, this method initializes the cell by calling its
>   init(style:reuseIdentifier:) method. For nib-based cells, this method
>   loads the cell object from the provided nib file. If an existing cell
>   was available for reuse, this method calls the cell’s
>   prepareForReuse() method instead.

So you should be able to distinguish both cases and respond accordingly.